# MVC 5 Custom validator

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, validation

I have a Custom Validator on ASP.net MVC 5. The server code works fine, but my client code doesn't work.

In the client I have this code:

```
 $.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add("birth", {}, function (options) {
     options.messages['birth'] = options.message;
 });

 $.validator.addMethod("birth", function (value, element, params) {
     return false;
 });

 $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(document);
```

The adapter add method work fine because the html tag contains the data-val-birth attribute with the error message indicated in the model, but when I submit the form, the validation doesn't work.

The javascript files are included and all seems to be well done. I've tried everything.

Help, please!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem with this code:

```
$.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add("birth", function (options) {
    $.validator.addMethod("data-val-birth", function (value, element, params) {
        return false;
    }, options.message);
});

$.validator.unobtrusive.parse(document);
```

I'm not convinced, but it works.
I will continue researching this.